# Why are some of my modules not loading correctly?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, python-module

I have a program which works fine when running it from Eclipse but fails when trying to run it from the command line.

There are a number of modules inside a root directory.

```
|_ Package
  |
  |_ module_1
    |_ __init__.py
    |_ config.py
  |
  |_ module_2
    |_ __init__.py
    |_ some_file.py
  |
  |_ module_3
    |_ __init__.py
    |_ some_other_file.py
  |
  |_ module_4
    |_ __init__.py
    |_ main.py
```

My main method is `module_4.main.main()` and at the top of `module_4.main.py` I make the imports:

```
from module_1 import config
from module_2 import some_file
from module_3 import some_other_file
```

When I run `python -m module_4.main` from the command line and in the `Package` directory I get: `ImportError: No module named module_3` at the third line, but the module on the previous line imports fine.

However if I run it from inside Eclipse it works fine and finds the package with no problems.

Two questions:

1. What could explain this kind of behaviour?
2. How do I go about debugging this?

Comment: Can you specify/tag which version of Python you're using?

Comment: Have added the 2.7 tag

Comment: Running from the `Package` directory.

Comment: I do have more than one version, but not in the active `conda` environment.

Comment: Have you tried running python with the `-v` option? Also, can you specify what (if anything) is in each of your `__init__.py` files?

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  I duplicated your directory structure, and made all the files empty except for `module_4/main.py`.  Running `python -m module_4.main` runs without problems.  If Python is getting to line 3 of `module_4.main`, then I'd suspect something in `module_3/__init__.py` or `module_3/some_other_file.py` is causing problems.

Comment: The `__init.py__` files are empty. And running with the `-v` option gives me a lot of Continuum Analytics imports, followed by: `python: can't open file module_4.main': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: @Chris I'm sure you're right, I'm just unsure how to go about finding out what the problem is since I can't reproduce it in Eclipse where I have a debugger available.

Comment: Can you change your import statement to just `import module_3` to rule out a problem with `module_3.some_other_file`?
Can you use `strace` to ensure python is finding `module_3/__init__.py`?

Comment: That is strange that you're getting a completely different (and even more bizarre) error with `-v`.  I agree that `strace` (if you're running on linux) might help.

Comment: Ah, that did the trick. I tried commenting out the import statement as suggested everything imported ok. So then tried adding them back in one at a time until I found the one that was breaking things. Then looking at the contents I realise there is an `os.chdir(THIS_DIR)` statement. Commenting that out solves the import problem, and time/unittest will tell what if anything that breaks...

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` file in the Package directory itself?

Comment: Why on earth would a module contain an `os.chdir` call?

Comment: No idea. It's been there for at least six months though (when I took this package on) without causing any harm when running from inside Eclipse.